# android studio gives can't resolve symbol when changing app name

Tags: java, android, image, filter

I have changed my app name after that i find one of the libraries that i import give can't resolve symbol :

```
import Catalano.Imaging.FastBitmap;
import Catalano.Imaging.Filters.GaussianBlur;
import Catalano.Imaging.Filters.Grayscale;
import Catalano.Imaging.Filters.Invert;
```

but it is working when i run the application even the filters i'm using from this library are working 
i tried to clean and rebuild the project and even deleting and adding the libraries again but still can't resolve symbol 
what is the problem here ??

Comment: Did you try re-importing the project?

Comment: yes but still have the same problem @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas